# docker stack deploy using the client api

Tags: go, docker

I'm playing with docker's [client api](https://godoc.org/github.com/docker/docker/client). I've seen how to run containers, pushing, pulling, etc. Now I want to deploy a stack with a compose file, but I don't think there's a one-func-call to do that (not in the client api anyway). I went trough docker's code and saw [how they do it](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/5706d8206bd41fca36ed634f80fe85f5ffbed71b/cli/command/stack/deploy.go).

Is this the only way? I'm trying to keep the dependencies to a minimum, but if there aren't other options I guess I could live with it. Also I'm still pretty new to golang, so if someone could provide an example of how can I achieve `docker stack deploy --compose-file file.yml` though go code will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: to deploy go code, build Docker container from your service written in go. If you are asking about archestration, than you can use kubernetes or Swarm. If you areasking for deployment automation tools, you shouldtake a  look on ansible.

Comment: @Altenrion my goal is to to execute docker commands (particularly - docker stack deploy) from my own go app and I was wondering what is the best way to do that. Currently I'm looking at the docker/cli/command package, which I think is the closest to what I need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some more research I think I have 3 options:

1. just use os/exec package and `exec.Command("docker", ...)`. This is ok, but it requires the docker client
2. use the stuff provided by the [docker/client](https://godoc.org/github.com/docker/docker/client) package and implement the call yourself. This gives you the most control, but you need to implement composite calls (docker stack deploy) e.g. create images, networks, start containers, etc.
3. use the commands provided by the [docker/cli/command](https://godoc.org/github.com/docker/docker/cli/command) package. This way you also have access to some configs that could be overriden and you let the docker guys worry about composite calls.

I ended up using #3, here's my code:

```
import (
    "os"
    "github.com/docker/docker/cli/command"
    "github.com/docker/docker/cli/command/stack"
    "github.com/docker/docker/cli/flags"
)

func main() {
    cli := command.NewDockerCli(os.Stdin, os.Stdout, os.Stderr)
    cli.Initialize(flags.NewClientOptions())
    cmd := stack.NewStackCommand(cli)

    // the command package will pick up these, but you could override if you need to
    // cmd.SetArgs([]string{"deploy", "--compose-file", "compose.yml", "mystack"})

    cmd.Execute()
}
```